# How to restructure object with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

How to turn an object from this one:

```
{
  "x1": {
    "src": "https://....png",
    "webp": "https://....webp"
  },
  "x2": {
    "src": "https://....png",
    "webp": "https://....webp"
  }
}
```

to this one:

```
[
  {
    srcSet: 'https://....webp 1x, https://....webp 2x'
  },
  {
     srcSet: 'https://....png 1x, https://....png 2x'
  }
]
```

I'm stuck with it, tried different object methods but always coming up with the same code which doesn't work as I expect it.

Comment: `Object.values` then `.map`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could get the entries and then map the values with keys for each index.

```js
var data = { x1: { src: "https://....png", webp: "https://....webp" }, x2: { src: "https://....png", webp: "https://....webp" } },
    result = Object
        .entries(data)
        .reduce((r, [k, o]) => Object
            .values(o)
            .map((p, i) => ({ srcSet: [].concat(r[i] && r[i].srcSet || [], `${p} ${k}`).join(', ') })),
             []
        );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one-liner approach:

```js
const obj = {
  "x1": {
    "src": "https://....png",
    "webp": "https://....webp"
  },
  "x2": {
    "src": "https://....png",
    "webp": "https://....webp"
  }
}

// one-liner
const result = Object
.entries(obj)
.map(r => ({ srcSet: Object.values(r[1]).map(v => [v, r[0]].join(' ')).join(',') }));

console.log(result);
```